# What's best practice for keeping gitlab-ci.yml immutable?

Tags: security, gitlab-ci

I want to keep our gitlab-ci.yml immutable for most of the group members.  How do I do that effectively?

These users contribute code, and must deploy code as part of a merge to develop-branch, so I cannot simply remove their access to the main project's repo, nor protect the develop branch (because then they can't run the pipeline).

I tried a trigger job to a CI file located at another project, but I'm starting to think I can't both allow project YIN to trigger YANG, while preventing these contractors from messing with the deploy script that I relocated from Yin to Yang in the hopes of locking it off.

1. I suspect that, in order to merge commit into project Yin and have it trigger the deployment in Yang, that a user would have to hold Developer access in Yang or higher ... which means they get to commit to Yang too, on any branch containing the gitlab-ci.yml file they'd be triggering.  True?

(I can't chastise them nor just fire them.  Half the challenge is a language issue, and the other is inexperience with not touching things that don't belong to you)

Thank you for your time.  The new trigger: syntax seems to be working much better (read: at all) than the old curl-the-api-URL-and pray trick, so there's that, at least.  If that's usable, it'd be ideal, still, but the real goal is an immutable gitlab-ci.yml, so any method toward that success would be great.

Comment: Run a test with the language you want, expected the content you want to keep compare to a `cat ./gitlab-ci`, so now if one space change on your gitlab-ci, test don't pass so nothing go to the next step. it's maybe to much basic, but will avoid mistakes

Comment: But 1) putting that checksum into gitlab-ci will change gitlab-ci, which will make it never pass its own signature check.  and 2) they could remove or change a checksum if they're just too busy to do a code review, and the check would be disabled.